# MySql UPDATE of tiny table is costly (0.2sec) - how to analyse further

Tags: mysql, mariadb

While optimizing some indexes I detected a curious case in the slow_query_log.

These are not the actual tablenames but for simplicity:

```
# Thread_id: 1293932  Schema: xx  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.205087  Lock_time: 0.000046  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 1  Bytes_sent: 52
UPDATE language SET lastUpdate = current_timestamp() WHERE languageID = '12';
```

Table 'language' has exactly 12 rows. It has only a few columns. It has only 1 index: the primary key on languageID (INT). This is thus the simplest table you can imagine. Why is this update statement taking 0.2 seconds?

For reference, select statements on rows of 10k-100k's of rows are quite fast:

```
# Thread_id: 1294423  Schema: xx  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.111802  Lock_time: 0.000266  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 14279
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 50
INSERT INTO session (sessionID, personID, lastDate)
    SELECT 8, a.personID, current_timestamp() FROM personA a INNER JOIN personP p on p.personID = a.personID LEFT OUTER JOIN view_bigViewB ON view_bigViewB.personID = a.personID WHERE view_bigViewB.someValue = 'x' ;
```

Above query is simplified a lot, and please do not pay too much atention to it, but let's say this is really a dramatic big data set that is being processed in only 0.1sec with full table scans. It is an INSERT that did not insert any rows, so no write operation was needed.

Of course, a write operation is more costly but 0.2s seems just too slow. How can I analyze what exactly is making up this .2 seconds?

Using MariadDb 10.3.27

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE

CREATE TABLE `language` 
( 
   `languageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
   `lastUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`languageID`) 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=16 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Output of innodb-parameters: https://pastebin.com/ReGHc1xp

Comment: What is the column type of languageID? Does your update improve if you remove the single quotes around the 12? If the column is a numeric type the quotes aren't needed and really shouldn't be used.

Comment: Is the ~0.2s "slowness" with that query repeatedly reproducible?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like you are using MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

Comment: @Dave it is an INT. No removing the queotes does not make a difference.

Comment: @J.D. Yes this query keeps returning in the logs. I have also see it in other tables, eg small Wordpress tables where an update is performed.

Comment: @RickJames It is InnoDB:
```CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `languageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaignID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;```

Comment: Isn't the primary key supposed to be ``PRIMARY KEY (`languageID`)` ` ???

Comment: @S.Roose I updated your question with the CREATE TABLE statement you provided above (for future reference please update your question with the additional information instead of commenting). Could you also include the CREATE INDEX statement on that Table too please? While 0.2s does seem a little odd it isn't necessarily a bad thing, are you experiencing any resultant performance issues in your consuming applications due to this?

Comment: Thanks. There are no other indexes than the Primary. @RolandoMySQLDBA yes that was a typo. I'm changing the original names to have a more comprehensible example.

I am not experiencing performance issues with this statement, it is just out of curiosity and it just feels high.

Comment: How much RAM?  (128M for buffer_pool is dangerously low.)

Comment: @RickJames This machine has 2GB of RAM of which the Mysql server uses 300-400Mb.

Answer (score 1):

Your innodb system variables indicate the innodb buffer pool is at 128M (the default). Its quite possible that the slowness of this single PK based update was due to this table not being in the innodb buffer pool. Look at the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%'` and adjust the pool size up until the `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` vs `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` is very small (<1%).

This will be the case if 128M of more recently used innodb tables are in memory.

Another potential cause if there is a significant amount of write activity on the the server the innodb flushing /writing could be causing a delay because of storage limits.

If a f{data}sync of the disk can take 0.2 seconds occasionally that could correspond to the query time.

Comment: Increasing the buffer_pool may keep other tables/queries from interfering with the `UPDATE` in question -- that is what I expect is the issue.

Comment: checked reads/read_requests, it is only 0.0002%. Edit: I have multiple databases on this server; Is there a way to get these statistics for a specific database?

Comment: @S.Roose - Clarification, please.  "Database" could mean "server", "VM with MariaDB", "instances of MariaDB", or "CREATE DATABASE".  Which?  The slowlog and the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` refer to all databases within one MariaDB instance.

Comment: @RickJames that is 1 MariaDB server: 1 instance with many databases (schemas in Oracle lingo)